# If $a,b$ are natural numbers such that $a^3+b^3$ is a perfect square, prove that $a+b$ can't be equal to the product of two different prime numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers

If $a,b$ are natural numbers such that $a^3+b^3$ is a **perfect square**, prove that $a+b$ can't be equal to the product of **two different prime** numbers.

I've tried to find some congruencies that would help me prove a contradiction, but that came to nothing.

I think the solution has something to do with the fact that
$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$

But, I'm not sure where to go from there, could someone tell me if I'm on the right path and give me a clue, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Please update your question to show what you tried with using congruences since that can be made to work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I tested a lot of congruences but didn't see anything that would be worth while pursuing, did I miss something? What modulo should I look at?

Comment: You're welcome for the comment. Did you try assuming $a + b$ is the product of two different prime numbers and then using that as your modulo to check with?

Comment: Hi, sorry if I'm misinterpreting your comment. Are you suggesting for me to check the congruencies of $(a^2-ab+b^2)$ modulo $pq$ where p and q are some prime numbers.

Comment: Yes, I'm basically suggesting you do that, but where $p$ and $q$ are not just *some* prime numbers but, rather, specifically where $a + b = pq$.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate further, should I actually look for an example where that's true or? I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, but I've just recently started learning congruencies so I'm not really well versed in this type of stuff.

Comment: I suggest using contradiction, where you assume $a + b = pq$ but then determine this doesn't work due to the requirement that $a^3 + b^3$ is a perfect square, with what that means for the value of $(a^2 - ab + b^2)$ modulo $pq$. Try this and, if you can't solve the problem, then put what you got into your question. This will allow somebody to help show you what, if anything, you did incorrectly, how to get past any point where you got stuck, etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$a^3+b^3=(a+b)((a+b)^2-3ab)$$ If $p$ is one of the two primes that divide $a+b$ then since $a^3+b^3$ is a square,
$$p|((a+b)^2-3ab)$$ so $p|3ab$ and since there are two primes we can assume that $p\neq 3$. Then say $p|a$ as $p|a+b$ we have $p|b$ also. Let $a=px$ $b=py$ then

$$x^3+y^3=(x+y)((x+y)^2-3xy)$$ which is divisible by $q^2$, $q$ being the other prime dividing $a+b$ and is also divisible at least once by $p$. Now that $x+y=q$ so we have

$$x^3+y^3=q(q^2-3xy)$$

and thus $q|3xy$  if $q|x$ or $|y$  then it divides both. And $x+y$ is not prime. Thus $q=3$.

So finally $x+y=3$, and therefore $x=2, y=1$. ($x=0$ is clearly impossible.)

and we have

$$2^3+1=3(9-6)$$ however this is not divisible by the other prime $p$.

Comment: Could be more clear in a few places. Should emphasize that from  $a=px, b=py,$ that $\frac{a+b}{p} = x+y$ and $a+b=pq \implies q = x+y$. Then if $q|x$ or $q|y$, then $x+y > q$, so I think you mean $x+y$ IS prime and $q$ must be $3$. Finally WLOG $x = 2, y=1$. I am not understanding the final statement. Why must it be divisible by $p$?

Comment: Thanks for those comments. Sorry it is hard to follow, you seem to have grasped it though. In going from $a^3+b^3$ to $x^3+y^3$ we are dividing by $p^3$, and as the former is a perfect square, it is divisible by an even power of $p$. Therefore $p$ must divide the latter at least once.